# If I know the Row and I calculate the column, how do I make this a cell reference?

Tags: worksheet-function, cells

Here's my scenario:
I find the row in a table using the "match" function. Can I use this value to reference a cell in the row I've found.
For example, if, in cell B7, the match function returns a value of 3. Can I use the value in cell B7 to reference a particular cell in row X (I'm looking to get a cell address of X3, so that I can decrement the value in cell X3 by 1.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are different ways to use the 3 -> X. However, the "so I can decrement...." needs some more clarification. Is X3 a value like 7 or is it a formula like =2+5. This makes a difference on how to implement. Each type requires a significantly different answer

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(X:X,B7)
```

Of Course you can skip the middle step and put your MATCH function in stead of B7:

```
=INDEX(X:X,MATCH(...))
```